# How to compute minimal edits to a JSON document for a VSCode WorkspaceEdit?

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, parsing, vscode-extensions

I want to build a custom editor following this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors

My editor is also backed by JSON, but when studying the example it says

```js
// Just replace the entire document every time for this example extension.
// A more complete extension should compute minimal edits instead.
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/bb473a1724d7595006760a9dfdc31e2429fa6cc7/custom-editor-sample/src/catScratchEditor.ts#L196-L197

How do I actually concretely do this?

Since the VSCode settings editor is also a GUI for a JSON file, is there some API to turn JSON changes into document edits?

Or are there JSON parsers that have some sort of red-green tree based structure to relate JSON data back to source location?

Comment: I wonder what really the benefit of this would be though. like- when you save, it's not like it's going to make any difference to work to write the new file content to disk (at least- I don't think)... I suppose it could save space in VS Code's memory for its undo history.

Comment: I don't think it will go over well if you shuttle a few MB of JSON between the webview and the node process on every keypress ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [jsonc-parser](https://github.com/microsoft/node-jsonc-parser) which has an API for applying modifications to a JSON document and generating text offsets and such. It is authored by Microsoft and seems widely used within VSCode

```js
/**
 * Computes the edit operations needed to modify a value in the JSON document.
 * 
 * @param documentText The input text 
 * @param path The path of the value to change. The path represents either to the document root, a property or an array item.
 * If the path points to an non-existing property or item, it will be created. 
 * @param value The new value for the specified property or item. If the value is undefined,
 * the property or item will be removed.
 * @param options Options
 * @returns The edit operations describing the changes to the original document, following the format described in {@linkcode EditResult}.
 * To apply the edit operations to the input, use {@linkcode applyEdits}.
 */
export function modify(text: string, path: JSONPath, value: any, options: ModificationOptions): EditResult;
```