# How do I build a responsive and robust CustomTextEditorProvider JSON editor VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VS Code extension that is a graphical editor backed by JSON data.

So I've implemented a `CustomTextEditorProvider` using jsonc-parser to compute minimal edits to the JSON document.

The challenge is how to have local update while avoiding race conditions and update loops. My current process is as follows:

The webview is seeded with an initial copy of the JSON document, and maintains both a text copy and parsed data as well as a version number. When it changes the data, it uses jsonc-parses `modify` and `applyEdits` to compute the changes needed to the text document, which it then `vscode.postMessage` to the extension.

On the extension side I listen for update messages and push them on a queue, and then launch a debounced task to compute a `WorkspaceEdit`. This is done to avoid edit conflicts that I was seeing, but feels kind of sketchy if anything is particularly slow. I found a suggestion to await the promise returned by the previous edit operation, but if you have 3 edits in quick succession the last two would await the same promise and still conflict.

When the VS Code document is changed, I send those edits to the webview, along with the document version number. Then in the webview I compare the version numbers, and if the document version number is higher, I apply the edit and reparse the webview state. The idea being that if the webview updates the state and increment the version, it'll loop around and get ignored, but if something else edits it the version number will be higher. However, this leaves a race condition where an external edit arrives before a local edit has looped around, in which case the wrong one will be ignored.

So there are at least two race conditions that I know of, and maybe more. I think the first one is easy enough to fix if I think about queues and promises a bit more. The second is more tricky I feel.

This editor used to be backed by CouchDB, I bring this up because of its concurrency model. Maybe what I need is a `_rev` like document version that includes a hash to compare-and-set updates or reject them. But then you'd also need some retry mechanism, which just isn't a thing here. A poor mans substitute could be that if the versions don't match we just request a full copy of the document.

But surely I'm not the first person to build an editor in VS Code so maybe there are tried and true solutions that I'm missing?

This is sort of a followup of [How to compute minimal edits to a JSON document for a VSCode WorkspaceEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591085/how-to-compute-minimal-edits-to-a-json-document-for-a-vscode-workspaceedit) and the code is here https://github.com/NyanCAD/Mosaic/tree/vscode